# Android ArrayAdapter from Class access to specific elements

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I try to write an quiz app for Android in Kotlin.
I take all data from API and create data classes

Quiz

```
    data class Quiz(
    val answerIds: List<Any>,
    val groupCodes: List<Any>,
    val questionList: List<Question>
)
```

Question

```
    data class Question(
    val answers: List<Answer>,
    val groupCode: String,
    val hasSimilarQuestions: Boolean,
    val id: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

Answer

```
data class Answer(
    val addsGroupCodes: List<String>,
    val id: Int,
    val questionId: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

I use Volley to make http request

My problem is:
I try to display only text from answers to specific question in ListView.
I create ArrayAdapter but I can not display only text of certain answer

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val url = ""
        showQuiz(url);
    }

    private fun showQuiz(url:String)
    {
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val pytanie : TextView = findViewById(R.id.pytanie)

        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, object : Response.Listener<JSONObject?>
        {
            override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject?) {
                try
                {
                    val jsonArray = response?.getJSONArray("questionList")
                    if (jsonArray != null)
                    {
                        val quiz:Quiz = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Quiz::class.java)
                        val odp = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.odpowiedzi) 

                        for (question in quiz.questionList)
                        {
                            val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<Answer> = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, question.answers)
                            odp.adapter = arrayAdapter
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

        },
                object : Response.ErrorListener
                {
                     override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError)
            {
                error.printStackTrace()
                Log.d("JsonObjectErr",error.toString());
            }
        }
        )
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}
```

What about access to other elements in ArrayAdapter, because I need to remember what user choose.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` shows value from `toString()` of an item.

So override `toString()` in `Answer` and return only value you want to show.